# Laravel Pusher: Get all users connected to Presence Channel

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

Does anyone know how te get all connected users from a Presence channel? I need them in my API Controller and save all of them in a database.

I found some people use `Pusher::get()` but then I get an error saying `Non-static method Pusher\Pusher::get() should not be called statically`.
I've seen others use `$this->pusher('/channels')`, but where do I get the $pusher instance from?

Sorry, maybe a noob question?

Comment: `Non-static method Pusher\Pusher::get() should not be called statically` Did you tried to replace `Pusher::get()` by `Pusher->get()`?

Comment: @ThanLUONG that gives me `unexpected '->'`. I think I need `$this->pusher`, but don't know how to get the push instance in my controller. Or maybe this isn't the way to go at all?

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: That's the problem, there is no code yet. I just have Pusher installed, have 1 Presence channel where connected users listen to and everybody who is connected can retrieve the other connected users in de frontend (via laravel-echo). One of the connected users sends an API request to a Controller to 'start a game'. But in this controller I need all the players that are connected to the same channel as the user sending the api request.

Comment: You could try this link: https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/71. You create object `Pusher\Pusher` with required information. Then, you get channel you want.

Comment: Please let me know the result after you try it.

Answer (score 5):

`$pusher` is the actual Pusher SDK instance, and you'll have to instantiate it yourself:

```php
$connection = config('broadcasting.connections.pusher');
$pusher = new Pusher(
    $connection['key'],
    $connection['secret'],
    $connection['app_id'],
    $connection['options'] ?? []
);

// Example 1: get all active channels
$channels = $pusher->get_channels();

// Example 2: Get all the connected users for a specific channel
$users = $pusher->get('/channels/<channel-name>/users');
```

Btw, this is also how Laravel does it internally if you look [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php#L214).

Comment: This also works well with Laravel Websockets library by BeyondCode, when it's used as [Pusher replacement](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/pusher)

Comment: I have tried it with Laravel WebSockets, and it always returns an empty array.

Comment: It seems that restarting the WebSocket service is necessary after adding the code to a controller; now it works perfectly! Thank you very much!!